# Clarification on Lazy Evaluation and its efficiency

Tags: lazy-evaluation, haskell

I came across following sentence on Real World Haskell:

> Lazy evaluation has some spooky effects. Let's say we want to find the
>   k least-valued elements of an unsorted list. In a traditional
>   language, the obvious approach would be to sort the list and take the
>   first k elements, but this is expensive. For efficiency, we would
>   instead write a special function that takes these values in one pass,
>   and it would have to perform some moderately complex book-keeping. In
>   Haskell, the sort-then-take approach actually performs well: laziness
>   ensures that the list will only be sorted enough to find the k minimal
>   elements.

And they give an code implemntation for that:

```
minima k xs = take k (sort xs)
```

But is that so ? I think even in Haskell it should do a full sort of the list to take out the `k` elements. ( Imagine having the smallest number at the end of the list ). Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Is finding the smallest element equivalent to sorting the whole list? Assume doing quicksort (It might not be the actual implementation though) where you partition the array around the pivot element and then recursively sort left and right half of the array. If you are asking just for elements on the left half then there is no need to sort the right half.

Comment: @Satvik Put that text in an answer, mate!

Comment: As usual this is a better example of the composability and separation-of-concerns gains, rather than the efficiency of lazy evaluation per se.

Comment: @Sibi: Nobody said that this implementation wouldn't have to read through all of `xs`, but it doesn't have to finish the job of sorting `xs`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I can understand it now. @Satvik If you can post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: @satvik: Would the same thing work with a merge sort?

Comment: @kqr Yep, which is a good thing, since GHC's `sort` is a merge sort. =)

Comment: There is also a detailed post on lazy quicksort by Heinrich Apfelmus http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/quicksearch.html

Comment: Heinrich Apfelmus crucially assumes that the quicksort "always uses a good pivot". without that, it's *O(n^2 + kn)* in the worst case (the descending list input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just putting my comment to answer here) Traversing the whole list is not equivalent to sorting it. Assume doing quicksort where you partition the list around the pivot and then recursively sort left and right half of the list. If you are asking just for elements on the left half then there is no need to sort the right half. This argument can be applied recursively. Thus if you are taking `k` elements from `n` length list after sorting, the complexity is `O(n + klog k)` and not `O(n log n)`. As pointed by @MoFu, Heinrich has a good blog post [here](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/quicksearch.html).