# Fibonacci sequence generation

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I was writing a fibonacci sequence generator, and I was trying to understand the following code in Haskell

`fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`

I understand what `zipWith` is, but I do not exactly know how the program executes and why it does generate all the fibonacci numbers. I was trying to understand why it does not terminate using the environment concept in functional languages as follows:

Initially, because Haskell's lazy evaluation, the binding in the `env` should be `fibs : [1,1,x]`, then to evaluate `fibs`, the interpreter evaluates `x` which is `zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` in this case. When evaluating `zipWith`, it gets `fibs : [1,1,2,x]`, again because of the lazy evaluation of Haskell. And `fibs` in `env` is bound to `[1,1,2,x]` at this time. However, to fully evaluate `fibs`, it continues to evaluate `x` and we go back to the previous steps.

Is this correct?

Besides, I noticed that when I ran the program above in `ghci`, it instantly prompts the fibonacci sequence it currently has computed, why? Shouldn't it print the result once it finishes all the computation?

Comment: [See one of my answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704503/lazy-evaluation-why-is-it-faster-advantages-vs-disadvantages-mechanics-why-i/24705697#24705697) that explains more of how this computation works from the "lazy" point of view.  One of the side effects of this is that when you evaluate this in GHCi, it's actually getting passed to `print`, which can lazily consume lists, printing each element as its available.  The `fibs` list you have defined is actually infinite, you can't actually compute the entire thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, most of your reasoning is correct. In particular, you described correctly how each new element of the list is evaluated in terms of older ones. You are also correct that to *fully* evaluate `fibs` would require repeating the steps you outlined and would, in fact, loop forever.

The key ingredient you're missing is that **we don't have to fully evaluate the list**. A binding like `fibs = ...` just assigns a name to the expression; it does not require evaluating the whole list. Haskell will only evaluate as much of the list as it needs to run `main`. So, for example, if our `main` is

```
main = print $ fibs !! 100
```

Haskell will only calculate the first 100 elements of `fibs` (following the steps you outlined) but will not need any more than that and will not loop forever.

Moreover, even if we *are* evaluating the whole thing (which will loop forever), we can use the parts we've calculated as we go along. This is exactly what's happening when you see the value of `fibs` in ghci: it prints as much as it can as each element is being calculated and does not have to wait until the whole list is ready.

### Seeing Strictness in GHCi

You can see how much of a list is evaluated in `ghci` using the `:sprint` command which will print a Haskell data structure with `_` for the parts that haven't been evaluated yet (called "thunks"). You can use this to see how `fibs` gets evaluated in action:

```
Prelude> let fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
Prelude> :sprint fibs
fibs = _
Prelude> print $ fibs !! 10
89
Prelude> :sprint fibs
fibs = _
```

Oops, that's not what we expected! In fact, this is a case where the *lack* of the monomorphism restriction is a problem! `fibs` gets a polymorphic type

```
Prelude> :t fibs
fibs :: Num a => [a]
```

which means it behaves like a function call each time you use it, not like a normal value. (In the background, GHC implements instantiating the `Num` type class as passing in a dictionary to `fibs`; it's implemented like a `NumDictionary a -> [a]` function.)

To really understand what's going on, we'll need to make `fibs` *monomorphic* explicitly. We can do this by loading it from a module where the restriction is active or by giving it an explicit type signature. Let's do the latter:

```
Prelude> let fibs :: [Integer]; fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
Prelude> :sprint fibs
fibs = _
Prelude> print $ fibs !! 10
89
Prelude> :sprint fibs
fibs = 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : 5 : 8 : 13 : 21 : 34 : 55 : 89 : _
```

And there you are: you can see which parts of the list needed to be evaluated and which ones didn't to get the 10th element. You can play around with other lists or other lazy data structures to get a good feel for what's going on in the background.

Also, you can take a look at [my blog post](http://jelv.is/blog/Lazy-Dynamic-Programming) about this sort of laziness. It goes into greater detail about the `fibs` example (with diagrams!) and talks about how to use this approach for general memoization and dynamic programming.

Comment: I didn't know about `:sprint`; that's pretty useful and a little terrifying. Is there a runtime version of `:sprint`, perhaps with the type `a -> IO Bool`? If so, it would have unsettling implications for ordinary evaluation being side-effect free.

Comment: @Cirdec: I believe that *exists*, in the same way that `unsafeCoerce` and `unsafePerformIO` exist: they're escape hatches to the abstraction that only make sense with an understanding of how it's actually implemented. I'm not sure exactly how it works though.