# Test if a value has been evaluated to weak head normal form

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, thunk, weak-head-normal-form

In Haskell, is it possible to test if a value has been evaluated to weak head normal form? If a function already exists, I would expect it to have a signature like

```
evaluated :: a -> IO Bool
```

There are a few places that similar functionality lives.

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28685367/414413) introduced me to the [`:sprint`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html#idp7742464) ghci command, which will print only the portion of a value that has already been forced to weak head normal form. `:sprint` can observe whether or not a value has been evaluated:

```
> let l = ['a'..]
> :sprint l
l = _
> head l
'a'
> :sprint l
l = 'a' : _
```

It's possible in `IO` to examine properties that would otherwise be off-limits. For example, it's possible to compare in `IO` to see if two values came from the same declaration. This is provided by the [`StableName`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Mem-StableName.html#t:StableName)s in `System.Mem.StableName` and used famously to solve the observable sharing problem in [data-reify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify). The related [`StablePtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Foreign-StablePtr.html) does not provide a mechanism to check if the referenced value is in weak head normal form.

Comment: Amusingly, this is already the second result in Google for "haskell check if whnf", at least for me :).

Comment: On a hopeful note, the [GHC Commentary](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects) suggests that each heap object info table includes the closure type, which *looks* like it should give you the kind of thing you're looking for. On a less-hopeful note, I have the feeling that GHC's unboxing transformation will make this whole idea rather slippery.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks. The GHC Commentary was very helpful in writing an [approximate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28701687/414413).

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure that there's anything pre-packaged for this. However, one can code it up:

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

track :: a -> IO (a, IO Bool)
track val = do
    ref <- newIORef False
    return
        ( unsafePerformIO (writeIORef ref True) `seq` val
        , readIORef ref
        )
```

Here's an example usage in ghci:

```
*NFTrack> (value, isEvaluated) <- track (undefined:undefined)
*NFTrack> isEvaluated
False
*NFTrack> case value of _:_ -> "neat!"
"neat!"
*NFTrack> isEvaluated
True
```

Of course, this will be tracking whether the *wrapped* write-and-then-return-the-original-value thunk is evaluated to WHNF, not whether the thing passed to `track` is evaluated to WHNF, so you'll want to put this as close to the thunk you're interested in as possible -- e.g. it will not be able to tell you whether a thunk made by somebody else has already been evaluated by somebody else before the tracking started. And of course consider using `MVar` instead of `IORef` if you need thread-safety.

Comment: I believe `NOINLINE` is usually needed around `unsafePerformIO` (along with asbestos underwear) to keep it from being optimized away.

Comment: AFAICS, here `False` means that the value is not in whnf, while `True` means that it is either in whnf _or_ it is being evaluated right now (and has not yet produced a whnf). Maybe using ``val `seq` unsafePerformIO (writeIORef ref True) `seq` val`` can lead to the opposite guarantee (`True` guaranteeing whnf, and `False` non-whnf/evaluation in progress). With a 3-states state one could represent this even more precisely: unevaluated/in progress/whnf.

Answer (score 9):

The [ghci implementation for `:sprint`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f17992a4954ac14cc6a3fe6a61ec6544a098da93/compiler/ghci/RtClosureInspect.hs#L174) ultimately uses [`unpackClosure#`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:unpackClosure-35-) from ghc-prim to inspect a closure. This can be combined with knowledge of the [format of heap objects](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/HeapObjects) to determine if a closure has been evaluated all the way to weak head normal form.

There are a few ways to reproduce the inspection done by the ghci implementation for `:sprint`. The GHC api exposes [`getClosureData :: DynFlags -> a -> IO Closure`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc/RtClosureInspect.html#v:getClosureData) in `RtClosureInspect`. The [vacuum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum) package, which depends only on ghc-prim, reproduces the code from `RtClosureInspect` and exposes `getClosure :: a -> IO Closure`. It's not immediately obvious how to examine either of these `Closure` representations to, for example, follow an indirection. The [ghc-heap-view](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view) package inspects closures and exposes both a [`getClosureData :: a -> IO Closure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view-0.5.3/docs/GHC-HeapView.html#v:getClosureData) and a [detailed view of the `Closure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view-0.5.3/docs/GHC-HeapView.html#t:GenClosure). ghc-heap-view depends on the GHC api.

We can write `evaluated` in terms of [`getBoxedClosureData`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-heap-view-0.5.3/docs/GHC-HeapView.html#v:getBoxedClosureData) from ghc-heap-view.

```
import GHC.HeapView

evaluated :: a -> IO Bool
evaluated = go . asBox
    where
        go box = do
            c <- getBoxedClosureData box
            case c of
                ThunkClosure     {} -> return False
                SelectorClosure  {} -> return False
                APClosure        {} -> return False
                APStackClosure   {} -> return False
                IndClosure       {indirectee = b'} -> go b'
                BlackholeClosure {indirectee = b'} -> go b'
                _ -> return True
```

This handling of blackhole closures may be incorrect while the blackhole is being evaluated. The handling of selector closures may be incorrect. The assumption that AP closures aren't in weak head normal form may be incorrect. The assumption that all other closures are in WHNF is almost certainly incorrect.

#### Example

Our example will require two concurrent threads to observe in one thread that the other is evaluating expressions.

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Concurrent
```

We can communicate information sideways out of a function without resorting to anything `unsafe` by selectively forcing evaluation. The following builds a stream of pairs of thunks in which we can choose to force one or the other of the pair.

```
mkBitStream :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
mkBitStream a = (a+2, a+3) : mkBitStream (a+1)
```

`zero` forces the first one and `one` forces the second one.

```
zero :: [(x, y)] -> [(x, y)]
zero ((x, _):t) = x `seq` t

one :: [(x, y)] -> [(x, y)]
one ((_, y):t) = y `seq` t
```

`copy` is an evil identity function that has the side effect of forcing bits in a stream based on inspecting the data.

```
copy :: (a -> Bool) -> [(x, y)] -> [a] -> [a]
copy f bs []     = []
copy f bs (x:xs) = let bs' = if f x then one bs else zero bs
                   in bs' `seq` (x:copy f bs' xs)
```

`readBs` reads our bit stream by checking if each of the thunks in a pair has been `evaluated`.

```
readBs :: [(x, y)] -> IO ()
readBs bs@((f, t):bs') = do
    f' <- evaluated f
    if f'
    then putStrLn "0" >> readBs bs'
    else do
        t' <- evaluated t
        if t'
        then putStrLn "1" >> readBs bs'
        else readBs bs
```

Forcing `copy` when printing it has the side effect of printing the information observed about the read string.

```
main = do
    let bs = mkBitStream 0
    forkIO (readBs bs)
    text <- getLine
    putStrLn (copy isAlpha bs text)
    getLine
```

If we run the program and provide the input `abc123` we observe the side effect corresponding to checking if each of the characters `isAlpha`

```
abc123
abc123
1
1
1
0
0
0
```

Comment: I think you could probably improve this answer by adding a brief description of at least the most relevant closure types.

Answer (score 7):

A negative answer, for the record: It does not appear to be feasible to reuse the mechanism of `sprint`, because it is tightly tied to interpreted interactive evaluation as opposed to primitive runtime structures — as far as I can tell; I've never looked at GHC internals before.

I started by searching for “sprint” in [the GHC source on GitHub](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/), which turns out to share an implementation with the “print” command but for a `Bool` flag called `force`, and followed definitions until I got to [RtClosureInspect.cvObtainTerm](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/f17992a4954ac14cc6a3fe6a61ec6544a098da93/compiler/ghci/RtClosureInspect.hs#L654) which appears to be a specialized evaluator.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful in writing an [approximate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28701687/414413). The closure inspection code used in `RtClosureInspect` is [exposed in the GHC api](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc/RtClosureInspect.html#v:getClosureData).

Answer (score 1):

There has been a proposal recently, maybe it's somewhere implemented already https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2015-February/024917.html