# React Native - FlatList ordering without sorting data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to render [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) rows in a certain order without sorting the data source?

**Example**

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'c'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

The above code renders a list

```
a
c
b
```

Is there a way to get it to render the following without sorting the data source?

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: I would say NO. What is the standard/creteria for your desired output? It is sorted by alphabet, right?

Comment: No, but Why do you need ?

Comment: This is simpler example for the real problem I am facing. I have a data source in a [normalized state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) so all my objects are referenced by id. I want to display the list in an order other than id without having to sort the entire thing, which could be large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are saying, I want Pizzar, but do not use sausage, meat, whatever. The answer is therefore No.

In order to perform **efficient** sorting and ordering, you can try [linq.js](https://github.com/neuecc/linq.js)

linq.js, in short is LINQ for JavaScript. Some particular useful/pertinent features include:

- implement all .NET 4.0 methods and many extra methods (inspiration from Rx, Achiral, Haskell, Ruby, etc...)
- complete [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704503/lazy-evaluation-why-is-it-faster-advantages-vs-disadvantages-mechanics-why-i)
- binding for Reactive Extensions for JavaScript(RxJS) and IntelliSense

If Linq.JS can solve your performance issue, you should sort it first and then render the sorted data source.

Another option is to use lodash, whose performance is claimed to be even better, see [this link](https://jsperf.com/linq-js-vs-lodash) for details.

[image]

Here are the code snippets to sort some data:
LINQ.JS:

```
var queryResult = $.Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
  .OrderBy(function(x) {
    return x.user.screen_name
  })
  .Select(function(x) {
    return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text
  })
  .ToArray();
```

Lodash:

```
var queryResults = _.chain(jsonArray)
.sortBy(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name })
.map(function(x) {
    return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text
  })
.value();
```