# Sorting react-native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sorting

How can I sort the `FlatList` by alphabetical order?

```
export default function PartnersList(props) {
  const { partners, onPartnerDetails } = props;

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={layout.list}
      contentContainerStyle={layout.listContainer}
      numColumns={2}
      data={partners}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (

        ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229682/react-native-flatlist-ordering-without-sorting-data

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Sorting `partners` would do the trick:

```
export default function PartnersList(props) {
  const { partners, onPartnerDetails } = props;

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={layout.list}
      contentContainerStyle={layout.listContainer}
      numColumns={2}
      data={partners.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (

        ...
```

This works if `partners` is an array of strings.

If it's an array of objects then you should sort by a string within that object.

for example if partner has a `name` property, sort must be:

```
....
data={partners.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))}
....
```

Comment: How to sort data with dates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-array-by-a-date-property